# Nginx http and https block configuration

Tags: http, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, https

I am setting up a load balancer that works with https and http if there isn't a https config file.

I have multiple virtual hosts that attempt to redirect http traffic to https (**type 1**) that are like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.xyz www.example.xyz;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.xyz;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/ssl/example.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/ssl/example.xyz/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass                              http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header                Host                            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP                       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
    }

}
```

and I also have one virtual host for all the http traffic (**type 2**) like this.

```
upstream myapp1 {
    server 8.8.8.8;
    server 8.8.4.4 backup;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

This setup is not working. I have two problems

1. The **type 1** virtual hosts are not redirecting to https.
2. I have the **type 1** configs for `foo.com`, `bar.com` and `baz.com` but `bar.com` and `baz.com` use the ssl cert from `foo.com`

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem try this to do the redirect:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

As you have two servernames configured, I prefer to use the host info directly from the incoming request. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host

For your second problem I can't say anything. Your pasted config looks fine. Make sure the different folders contain different certs ;-)